# Запрос в базу по неполным данным

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Есть сторонний обработчик который создает на выходе массив **array(32,15,42,64)**;

C моей стороны есть записи в базе в которых одно из полей содержит те же самые данные но в произвольном порядке **15,42,32,64**. В записях повторяться один и тот же набор данных из массива не может, данные всегда числовые. Отдельные элементы массива допустим **32** могут быть. Количество записей в базе увеличивается достаточно быстро. Делать **LIKE** запрос по одному элементу и обрабатывать потом запись **array_diff**'ом в поисках нужной на мой взгляд долго (возможно ошибаюсь).

Вопрос: есть ли способ сделать это запросом в базу не указывая точный порядок?

Comment: @Tehek, а нормализовать таблицу не вариант? То есть, вместо одной записи вида `("id", "1,2,3,4")` сделать 4 записи `("id", "1")`, `("id", "2")`, `("id", "3")`, `("id", "4")`.

Comment: значений может быть больше 4, добавлять каждый раз столбец не самый лучший вариант.
Структура таблицы примерно такая id, team_name, regdate, tag, players, ...
Собсно это поле players и нужно проверять. Игроков в одной команде может быть 5 а в другой 15.

Comment: т.е. по Вашему хранить кучу одинаковых записей на каждого игрока команды выгоднее чем перебирать потом тем же самом диффом меньшее количество записей? В принципе я согласен что и в остальной программе будет несколько проще делать обработки, если не делать explode, implode на каждой второй функции.

Comment: @Tehek, эти записи можно (и нужно) хранить в отдельной таблице. То есть, у вас будет отдельно таблица `teams`, в которой вы будете хранить сведения о команде (id, team_name, regdate, tag), и отдельно таблица `team_members`, в которой вы будете хранить списки игроков в каждой команде (team_id, player_id).

Comment: Да, тут я явно не подумал, спасибо за помощь. Пойду переделывать структуру бд и тонну кода :(
P.S. как на хэшкоде ставить имя собеседника в комментарий?

Comment: @Tehek, пожалуйста. Чтобы вставить имя собеседника, просто набирайте @ и имя (без пробела). А ещё в комментариях работает вся разметка, которую можно использовать в ответах и вопросах.

Comment: если в базе хранить числа отсортироваными, и с обработчика возвращать также, то можно будет обойтись обычным сравнением. Да, придется пробежать один раз по таблице и посортировать.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Tehek](/users/16506/tehek)](/users/16506/tehek), не самый лучший вариант (мягко говоря), вы уже сделали. Теперь вам бы хорошо задуматься, как исправить всё это. [[@fori1ton](/users/5577/fori1ton)](/users/5577/fori1ton), направляет вас в нужное русло, даже если будет сотня параметров. Если собираетесь стоять на своём, то пожалуйста, [вот вам такой вариант](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b7e97/13/0).

```
SELECT 
  `id`, `nums` 
FROM 
  `mytbl` 
WHERE 
  FIND_IN_SET('42', `nums`) 
  AND FIND_IN_SET('32', `nums`)
  AND FIND_IN_SET('15', `nums`)
  AND FIND_IN_SET('64', `nums`);
```